# Using a jvectormap of the US, how can I make 1/2 of a state a different color?

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

Can someone please suggest how, using a jvectormap of the US, I can make part of a state a different color.  I would like to make the bottom half of Missouri a different color than the top half.  I would also like to divide Illinois into East and West in a similar manner.

Here is the code I have currently.

```
  <div id="us-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('#us-map').vectorMap({
            map: 'us_aea_en',
            backgroundColor: '#c2e2f2',
            series: {
              regions: 
              [{values: {
                  "US-IL": '#858500',
                  "US-WI": '#05806D',
                  "US-MN": '#05806D',
                  "US-IA": '#05806D',
                  "US-CO": '#05806D',
                  "US-SD": '#05806D',
                  "US-KS": '#05806D',
                  "US-NE": '#05806D',
                  "US-IN": '#800517',
                  "US-MI": '#800517',
                  "US-MO": '#858500'
              },attribute: 'fill'}]
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
```

I have some experience programming, but am fairly new to JavaScript. Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: You'll probably need to convert your custom map outline into an svg so different parts of a state will have different coordinates which you can then target the specific coordinates

Comment: without modifying the map, you might be able to make the state transparent  and put a colored rectangle or two behind it. Since you have a fixed pixel size and right-angle splits, this wouldn't be very complicated.